# Insert Image into Layout then use in intent to Email App

Tags: java, android, image, email, android-intent

Ok, so what im trying to see if can be done. So i have a basic form submission for my application. Where the user can fill out some information such as a support request. This consists of several edit texts and view texts. Then its has a little text builder code in it to merge the text together and intent's to the android system for output via email.

So what i want to know is how i can add a image into this factor.

```
     public void onClick(View v) {
        String[] recipients = new String[]{"email@email.com", "email@email.com",};
          String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
          String message = "Name:\n" + nametext.getText().toString();
          message += "\n\nEmail:\n" + emailtext.getText().toString();
          message += "\n\nContact#:\n" + phonetext.getText().toString();
          message += "\n\nTopic:\n" + topictext.getText().toString();
          message += "\n\nDescription:\n" + detailstext.getText().toString();
          message += "\n\n" + sentby.toString();


          Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
          //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
          //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

          //need this to prompts email client only
          email.setType("message/rfc822");
          //plain text
          email.setType("text/plain");

          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client  :"));
          finish();

        }
    });
```

So here is the example code for the string builder code to merge whats being typed inside the edit text forms on the xml layout file.

Now what im trying to figure how to do, is what code i would need to add a insert image button on my xml layout, the code to select the image from the user's file manager or gallery app and then how i could add that into the overall intent to send via email.

Any suggestions, feedback, source code examples and anything helps. Thanks in advance.

### UPDATE

i have found the below code, and want to know if anybody has used this and if it will work in my above code.

```
 sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, "file:///sdcard/mysong.mp3");
```

Comment: have you tried the update code?

Comment: @toadzky i have not tried that code at this time. i dont know how i would do it for images that are capture from the app and saved to a specific folder however the string name is always different since i save the name of the image by the timestamp of my webview capture from the app. those are the images im trying to send(intent) into the email app to send out.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use android.net.Uri

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/mysong.mp3"));
```

it's work to attache file to email.